# Is there a command to view hard drive specs

Tags: command-line, hard-drive

I noticed that my Ubuntu is lagging EXTREMELY badly but only the first time I do things after what I did gets loaded into RAM the lag stops totally. I ran some tests and I guess one of my laptop hard drives is borked.

Im assuming that I have to replace the drive, is there some command I can issue to see the exact specs on the drive so I can then buy it online?

I don't want to have to open up the laptop, find the specs. Then open it again when the new drive arrives.

Comment: Or is there another cool hacky command or way to partition my drive to avoid using the bad spots? A while ago when my drive failed I mounted it useing an alternative superblock and this worked and still does i guess..

Comment: I found the hacky solution I wanted. I ran the command "badblocks /dev/sda1" and then noticed they were all near the front of the drive. So I created an unallocated partition at the front of the drive consisting of 50% of the total size. I then tested the second half of the drive! AND WALAAAAAAAA!!!!!! IT WORKED!!!!! Im going to buy a new drive anyway but this process taught me alot :)

Comment: I'm happy for you.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`smartctl` command from `smartmontools` package is what you want for that

```
% sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.13.0-24-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SAMSUNG SpinPoint M7
Device Model:     SAMSUNG HM250HI
Serial Number:    <snip>
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0024e9 203520f1d
Firmware Version: 2AC101C4
User Capacity:    250,059,350,016 bytes [250 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu May 15 21:49:09 2014 MYT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: That's a great answer thank you.

Answer (score 30):

You can use lshw tool :

**Install** :

```
sudo apt-get install lshw
```

Command for H.D.D Specs:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage
```

Comment: Thanks I hope this helps someone but the first answer was PERFECT so im not even bothering with this, do you know if I can somehow use only part of my hard drive? The hole thing still works but super slow. I know nothing of hardware but maybe there is a way to say only use the good part of the hard drive? Maybe when hard drives go bad only certain portions go bad?

Comment: Try to test it for bad boot sectors and repair them .

Comment: ok i will try to help you mate .

Comment: You already did! I ran the command "badblocks" to find bad boot sectors and it saved 50% of my drive!!! its working super fast :)! THANKS!!!

Comment: you are welcome my friend :) happy to hear that

Comment: On my system this only shows the controllers and not the attached SSD.

Comment: You need at least 125 reputation to cast a vote lol. I cast my vote here: bad answer.

Comment: On my system this only shows the controllers and not the attached SSD. This answer just does not work at 100%. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 25):

```
% sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda                                                                      ~

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD10JPCX-24UE4T0                    
        Serial Number:      WD-WXR1E24A7U0E
        Firmware Revision:  01.01A01
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = 16384 KBytes
        Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
```

Comment: A simple command that's installed by default with all the info I was looking for. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 20):

You can use lsblk, it has a ton of options that you can use e.g.:

```
lsblk -o MODEL,SIZE,NAME -d
```

which gives this result in my case

```
MODEL              SIZE NAME
Samsung SSD 850  232.9G sda
Samsung SSD 850  931.5G sdb
```

Answer (score 12):

$ lsblk

The command lsblk by default will list all block devices in a tree-like format. Type lsblk --help to see more options